# Can't combine brace expansion with parameter expansion in bash

Tags: bash, brace-expansion, parameter-expansion

```
$ set a b c
$ echo $1 $2 $3
a b c
$ echo ${1..3}
-bash: ${1..3}: bad substitution
```

I want to echo $1 $2 $3 with brace expansion.  But it doesn't work.

> The  order  of  expansions  is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a
>   left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

According to the bash manual, brace expansion is performed before parameter expansion.

So I think bash should perform brace expansion on `${1..3}` first, convert it to `echo $1 $2 $3`, and then perform parameter expansion.

However, the fact is that bash complains `${1..3}` is a bad substitution.
Why is that?

PS:
Thank you guys!All you answers are wonderful.But I think

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer is  closer to what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It thinks that the braces are part of the parameter substitution since it follows a dollar sign, and "$1..3" is an invalid variable name.

Try "${@:1:3}" instead.

Answer (score 3):

[Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32557798/12274) is the right way to do, but here's a bit more detail about how to make it work the way you started it.

You'd have liked `${1..3}` to expand to `$1 $2 $3`.  We can't concatenate `$` and `{1..3}` and have it work, or bash will interpret it as a parameter expansion (and fail).  To have it interpreted as brace expansion, neutralize the dollar sign by escaping it:

```
user$ echo \${1..3}
$1 $2 $3
```

As you noticed, it outputs dollar-expressions without evaluating them.  That's because quote removal (the part that converts `\$` back to `$`) is performed after parameter expansion.  So we'd need to run it back through `eval`:

```
user$ eval echo \${1..3}
a b c
```

More complex than needed when it could be written as `echo "$@"`

Comment: This should not be construed as a recommendation to *use* `eval`, though.